# Round function is truncating zero at the end in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = 0.02503
print(round(a,4))
```

Output below when i run the above code in Python 3.0 editor.

```
output: 0.025
```

But i want the output to be 0.0250, how to achieve this with proper rounding.

Comment: `0.025` and `0.0250` are the same number. If what you care about is how the number is displayed rather than the number itself, look into string formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of the `print` formatting, not the rounding:

```
a = 0.02503
b = round(a,4)

print(b)          # 0.025
print(f'{b:.4f}') # 0.0250
```

The `print(f'{b:.4f}')` prints `b` with for decimal places.